# Froala Editor garbles my code

Tags: editor, froala

I have been using Froala Editor (1.2.6) in a project of mine for a few weeks and it's been working great, but after I moved the project from my development environment to the production server I seem to be encountering a very strange bug(?).

For example, I have the following code in one of the pages that I am editing with Froala:

```
<div class="pageHeader">
  <div class="pageHeaderContent">
    <h1>Library</h1>

    <div class="breadcrumbs"><a class="ajaxify" href="../en/about-us">About Us</a> <i class="fa fa-chevron-circle-right"></i> Library</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Now, if I edit this page in anyway using Froala Editor (both HTML view the regular view) and save my changes, this is the result (only visible after reloading the editor):

```
<div class="\&quot;pageHeader" fr-tag\"="">
  <div class="\&quot;pageHeaderContent" fr-tag\"="">
    <h1 class="\&quot;fr-tag\&quot;">Library</h1>

    <div class="\&quot;breadcrumbs" fr-tag\"=""><a ..="" about-us%5c""="" ajaxify\""="" class="\" en="" href="%5C">About Us</a><em class="\" fa"="" fa-chevron-circle-right\"=""></em> Library</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I don't think the issue is related to the options I init the editor with, as I didn't change anything between moving from dev to production. Here are the options I am initializing with:

```
allowScript: true,
allowComments: true,
inlineMode: false,
tabSpace: true,
fileUploadURL: adminRoot+'ajax/uploadFile.php',
imageUploadURL: adminRoot+'ajax/uploadImage.php',
toolbarFixed: true,
imageDeleteURL: adminRoot+'ajax/deleteImage.php',
defaultImageWidth: 0,
imageResize: true
```

Does anybody have any idea what I can start trying to correct this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem, needed to run the output of getHTML through stripslashes before saving it to the file.